# Local shallow git cloning with hard-links

Tags: git, clone

On my local filesystem, I want to be able to only clone the head of git repo (A) so no history comes along to a new git repo (B).  But I want the benefits of hard-links for the files now in B to save on space.  Is there a way to do this?  Do the hard-links even help once repo A changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that it is impossible to do local shallow cloning with hard links among object databases, at least as of git 1.7.12. `git clone --depth 1 --single-branch` explicitly warns that `--depth` is ignored in local clones, and to use `file://`. So you will need to choose between hard links and shallow cloning.

The hard links do work even when repository changes, at least for a time, because git adds new objects to new files, and never modifies existing files. However, it does occasionally repack the object database for efficiency, and I don't see how the hard links could be preserved then.

If you choose shallow cloning, you can create the clone with `git clone --single-branch --depth 1 file://old_repo_dir` options. I find it annoying that `--depth 1` means 1 item of history, so you'll get not only the latest commit, but also its parent (or parents if it's a merge). The parent gets the commit message from the original repository, but the commit message lies because the commit in actuality contains the creation of the entire tree.

I prefer to start off with a single commit with a commit message of my choosing that creates the initial tree. This is obtained by first creating a new branch without history in the old repo, and then pulling that branch into the new empty repo. I tested this on a huge repo with a 664MB object database with 673k objects (the Emacs bzr repository converted to git). When the new repo received the pull, it had a 36MB object database with 3477 objects — so the excess content was apparently pruned. Here are the exact steps:

```
# at the old repo:
git checkout --orphan tmp-snapshot
git commit -m "Initial commit."

# at the new repo location:
git init
git pull OLD_REPO_DIR tmp-snapshot:master

# back at the old repo:
git branch -D tmp-snapshot   # no longer serves a purpose
```

Now the `master` branch of the new repo contains a single commit with a tree identical to the tree of the old repo, and without any history.

Comment: What happens to the branch in the parent?

Comment: Nothing; you get rid of it with `git branch -D` if you don't need it. That branch requires no additional space in the parent repo since it consists of a single commit that points to a tree that (obviously) already exists in the repo.

Comment: In current git versions `--depth` [implies](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) `--single-branch`.

Answer (score 2):

You can clone it and then recreate head commit stripping off parents. Considering your original repo's objects are likely to be in packs, you'd hardlink more than you want to, anyway. And yes, the hard links will stay intact for a while, but once you start doing gc or some such, the effect will likely be gone. You can also use alternates instead of hardlinks.

Look up the docs for `git commit-tree` to create a commit from the tree, I can't tell you the exact syntax.

Comment: `git checkout --orphan` followed by `git commit` creates a commit from the tree without resorting to plumbing.